# The entity type StudentDetail is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to insert data in multiple tables but got stuck when inserting it in another table,have seen similar error on others post but nothing worked for me,error is : -

**The entity type StudentDetail is not a part of the model for the current context.**

**Web Config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model3.csdl|res://*/Models.Model3.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model3.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\MSSQLSERVER2014;initial catalog=Sample;user id=sa;password=**;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**DbContext Class**

```
 public class ConnectionContext : DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DbSet<StudentDetail> StudentDetails { get; set; }

 }
```

**Student Model**

```
   public partial class Student
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

StudentDetails Model

```
[Table("StudentDetails")]
public partial class StudentDetail
{   
    [ForeignKey("FK_SD")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class StudentViewModel
 {
    public Student Students { get; set; }

    public StudentDetail StudentDetails { get; set; }

 }
```

**Action** 
      private ConnectionContext db = new ConnectionContext();

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(StudentViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.Students.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.Students.Add(model.Students);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var objstudetails = new StudentDetail
            {
                Id = model.Students.Id,
                Address = "SYDNEY"
            };

            //Here it breaks stating StudentDetails not a part of model..
            db.StudentDetails.Add(objstudetails);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model.Students);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have cleaned and rebuild the solution its working fine.